# How can I create a short version of this code block

Tags: java

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(
  new java.util.TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // my code is here card.getJLabel().setVisible(false);
      }
    }, 3000 // < my parameter);
```

How can I create a short function of this one, I use it in different functions so it would be clean if I can create short version of this one.

One more, I'm quite new to java, so what material i should read to know more about this particular subject. 
Thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

Presuming what can change from one call to the other is the `card` to be hidden and the `delay` before it gets hidden :

```
public void hideCard(MyCard card, long delay){
  new java.util.Timer().schedule(
     new java.util.TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         card.getJLabel().setVisible(false);
       }
     }, delay);
  }
```

Here is a good start to [refactoring](http://www.devdaily.com/java/refactoring-extract-method-java-example), and [refactoring with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecref/).

Answer (score 1):

Just put that snippet of code in a separate method and call the method each time you want to run the snippet of code:

```
public void scheduleHideCard() {
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // my code is here card.getJLabel().setVisible(false);
            }
        }, 3000 // < my parameter);
}
```

...and call the method by doing `scheduleHideCard()`.

If you're using Eclipse you can even select the snippet of code and do *Source -> Refactor -> Extract Method* and it will take care of extracting the appropriate parameters for you.

As a side-note: If you're using several classes from the `java.util` package, you may mant to import those classes at the top of the file:

```
import java.util.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract this code into a separate method like this?

```
void scheduleSomeActivity() {
  new java.util.Timer().schedule(...);
}
```

or possibly turning e.g. the delay into a parameter:

```
void scheduleSomeActivityWithDelay(long delay) {
  new java.util.Timer().schedule(..., delay);
}
```